# list column name disappear when i scroll down sharepoint

Tags: list

I have a list in sharepoint with 100 items per page.
As it show more items in page, the problem is when i scroll down I forget for which column name i want to view\edit data. Is there any jquery or javascript by which each column name or say whole column header can be visible if i scroll down to 100th item. It there any sharepoint out of box feature to sort the problem?

Please give me script i anyone have or any blog/link which can help me.

Answer (score 1):

What version of SharePoint are you using? Here are links to "sticky header" solutions for SharePoint 2013 and 2010:

[Sticky Headers in SharePoint 2013](http://spoodoo.com/sticky-headers-in-sharepoint-2013/)

[SharePoint 2010: Freeze Header Row of SharePoint List View](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18056.sharepoint-2010-freeze-header-row-of-sharepoint-list-view.aspx)

Note that these are not the only solutions that accomplish this, just ones I have had experience with in the past. If you search for "SharePoint [your version] fixed list view header row," you will see lots of other options that may work better for you.

Comment: not able to implement it in sharepoint 2010. Can you please help me wit the same.